# How to add/remove items in a ListBox with Button click in Dotvvm

Tags: dotvvm

Firstly, I tried a generic list but the data-bound ListBox on the view did not update when I added or removed items in the viewmodel. I then tried GridViewDataSet with a grid, still to no avail.

When I populate the list/GridViewDataSet with initial values then items are shown in the view.

Is there an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Can you show your ViewModel and DotHTML markup?

Comment: Is there a sample that shows how to add/remove items in a list dynamically using a button initiated command handler

Comment: It should work with `List<T>`, there is no need for the observable collection. 
How is your list declared? Is there both `{ get; set; }`? Are you using the `Bind` attribute?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Yes, it does work.